# LG Gram: writing to /sys/class/leds/input3::capslock/brightness doesn't do anything

Tags: keyboard, hardware

Usually on Linux you can turn your LEDs on and off by writing an ASCII number to `/sys/class/leds/*/brightness`, where `*` depends on the LED. The caps lock key on my LG Gram has an LED, but I can't turn it on. Here's all my LEDs:

```bash
$ ls /sys/class/leds
input16::capslock  input16::scrolllock  input3::numlock     kbd_backlight  tpad_led
input16::numlock   input3::capslock     input3::scrolllock  phy0-led
```

I tried `input16::capslock` and `input3::capslock` with no luck. Then I tried `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/*/brightness`, and the only effect was to turn on my keyboard backlight. My laptop also has an LED next to the charging port, one next to the power button, and one next to the camera which were also unaffected, but that's less surprising. I'm guessing this is an LG specific issue since I've been able to toggle the capslock LED on other laptops. Does anyone know what's going on?

As a side note, changing `kbd_backlight/brightness` causes the backlight to slowly fade in. Does anyone know if it's possible to change this so it turns on instantly?

Comment: can you do the following? 1. run `( cd /sys/class/leds/; for file in */brightness; do printf '%s: %d\n' "${file%/brightness}" "$(cat "${file}")"; done ) | sort | > /tmp/before`, 2. press the Caps Lock key to get the LED to light up. 3. `( cd /sys/class/leds/; for file in */brightness; do printf '%s: %d\n' "${file%/brightness}" "$(cat "${file}")"; done ) | sort | > /tmp/after` 4. `diff /tmp/before /tmp/after` to see the differences

Comment: The side note belongs to a new question. One issue per question please.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that side note feels like important hardware information, Kamil! Tells us that there's extensive firmware in the keyboard.

Comment: @MarcusMüller done: `15:47:24 ~ % cat /tmp/before
input18::capslock: 0
input18::numlock: 0
input18::scrolllock: 0
input3::capslock: 0
input3::numlock: 0
input3::scrolllock: 0
kbd_backlight: 0
phy0-led: 1
tpad_led: 0
15:47:30 ~ % cat /tmp/after
input18::capslock: 1
input18::numlock: 0
input18::scrolllock: 0
input3::capslock: 1
input3::numlock: 0
input3::scrolllock: 0
kbd_backlight: 0
phy0-led: 1
tpad_led: 0
15:47:35 ~ % diff /tmp/before /tmp/after
1c1
< input18::capslock: 0
---
> input18::capslock: 1
4c4
< input3::capslock: 0
---
> input3::capslock: 1`

Comment: @A.Kriegman could you add that output to your question instead? The comments "eat up the line breaks, and I'm having a hard time interpreting what you wrote.